# Can you change an issue's assignees on Github?

Tags: github

I have an issue opened in a Github project, and I want to change the person it's assigned to. Is there any way to do it using the web interface? A Google search only shows ways to do so through the API.

Comment: Is [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users) what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! That's it. I have to say, wouldn't it be more, erm, intuitive if you could do that from the issue itself, just the way you can assign it initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the issue itself by clicking the cog next to the Assignees header in the column on the right.  From there, a menu will pop up where you can clear the current assignees or search for new ones.

Comment: It's really odd, but I swear that when I asked the question, the cog icon didn't appear anywhere in my Github issue page (Safari MacOS 10.14). Now I've looked again... and it's there.